# taking text(dom element) and placing it into separate span and then making it appear alphabetically on the page

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gsap

Objective:

I have text from a dom element that will place each char into a span and each span will appear in alphabetical order. **Having trouble with the alphabetical part**

Code for placing each char into a separate span:

```
class SplitText{
    constructor(){

    }

    configureDomElement(domElement){

       let splitDomElement = domElement.textContent.split(''),
           span,
           spans = [];

           domElement.textContent = '';

            for(let i = 0; i < splitDomElement.length; i++){
                   span = document.createElement('span');
                   span.textContent = splitDomElement[i];
                   span.style.display ='inline-block';
                   span.id = 'span'+(i+1);

                   if(splitDomElement[i] === ' '){
                       span.style.paddingRight="1rem";
                   }

                   domElement.appendChild(span);
                   spans.push(span);
            };

       return spans;

    };


};


export default SplitText;
```

**Stuck here: 
Code for placing each char in alphabetical order and animation onto the screen:**

```
import SplitText from './SplitText';


class IntroAnimations{
    constructor() {

    }

    loadAnimations(){

        //text from dom element: cervini
        let loadingHeading = document.querySelector('#js-loading-heading');

        const configuredLoadingHeading = new SplitText().configureDomElement(loadingHeading);
        let sortedText;

        for(let i = 0; i < configuredLoadingHeading.length; i++){
            sortedText = configuredLoadingHeading[i].textContent.sort();
        }



        TweenLite.set(sortedText, {y: 0, opacity: 0});

        let tl = new TimelineLite();

        tl.staggerTo(sortedText, 4, {y: 0, opacity: 1}, 0.05);
}

};

export default IntroAnimations;
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the result you are getting? Looking at the code it appears that you are trying to sort individual span objects. I would recommend sorting the text first, then creating your span elements. If not, you should be able to write your own sort function that takes your array of spans and looks at the `span.textContent` to compare. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRomLX

Comment: Thank you. Trying to make the text remain in the order it is in but make each char appear only in alphabetical order.

Comment: You'd need to split by word `' '` then split each word into characters `''`, then sort. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRomLX